# Laravel, How to get the current HTTP status code in blade view error page eg. 404.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have generated error pages using Laravel's `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors` command.

Now inside, let's say 404.blade.php view, I want to get the status code of 404 and use it for a simple if-else case but I don't want to include any  tag around and later getting the variable, so I tried below

`http_response_code()` and `app('Illuminate\Http\Response')->status()`

But ironically, both sometimes return 200 as the http response code while I'm expecting to get 404.

What's the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't the status code in `404.blade.php` be..... 404?

Comment: You see, the command above will not work in all cases, unlike using this ```$exception->getStatusCode()``` variable that has been made available by Laravel in the blade view which will work in most cases if needed.

Comment: I get your point, but this is the case where I want to get the status code of the error page so I can decide to display content in the view or not and by using the above it will make the process flow lengthy. See the answer in action below

                  ```  @if($exception->getStatusCode() == 503)

                    @else

                               <a class="btn " href="{{ route('home') }}">Go Home</a>

                    @endif ```

Comment: But if I may ask why the downvote  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

And also, kindly contribute where necessary, so I can do better. Thank you

Comment: Lol, but I think the interaction has helped me revise the question better. Thank you by the way for the banter. Cheers...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220279/discussion-between-niilante-and-digitaldrifter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an instance of HttpException being passed to the custom 404 blade page.

The view could use the $exception variable that has been predefined by Laravel, to get http status code.

So if you leverage on this code `$exception->getStatusCode()` you will return 404.

Also, if you try this approach for any other error page you'll get the response code of the page.

> **NB:** This was tested in Laravel 7.X